# If every divisor of $x$ divides a number of the form $y^2+2$, what can be said about $x$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $x$ be a positive integer such that every divisor of $x$ (including $x$, of course) divides an integer of the form $y^2+2$.

By classical results, we know that every prime factor is of the form $a^2+2b^2$.

> **QUESTION**: Does $x$ have any special properties **beyond** that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since the set $E$ of numbers of the form $a^2+2b^2$ is a semigroup due to the generalized Lagrange's identity
$$ (a^2+2b^2)(c^2+2d^2) = (ac+2bd)^2 + 2(ad-bc)^2 $$
we have that $x$ itself belongs to $E$, for instance.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by the second sentence. (p.s. Fixed a typo in your answer.) So for every divisor $x_i = a^2+2b^2$ of $x$, we can say that there exist integers $c$ and $d$ such that the quotient $x/x_i = c^2+2d^2$ with $ad-bc = \pm 1$. However, does this lead inevitably to $x=z^2+2$ for some integer $z$?

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: nope, just consider the product between $11=3^2+2$ and $83=9^2+2$, that is not of the form $z^2+2$.

Comment: I didn't say every divisor is _of_ that form… simply that every divisor (including $x$ itself) _divides a number of that form_. In your example, what number of the form $z^2+2$ is divisible by $11 \cdot 83$? Perhaps there’s something in the knowledge of that which can be used to characterize $x$ [and/or its divisors].

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: oh, sorry, I misunderstood you. Well, the last problem can be solved through the CRT: we want that $z^2+2$ is divisible by both $11$ and $83$. $-2$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod{11}$ and $\pmod{83}$, hence it is enough to solve $z\equiv \pm 3\pmod{11}$ and $z\equiv \pm 9\pmod{83}$. $z=74$ is the smallest solution and $$74^2+2 = 2\cdot 3\cdot 11\cdot 83. $$